# how to add marker in google map?

Tags: javascript, php, dictionary

I am new to use javascript, anybody can help me to add a marker in the map?

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js ......  
<script>
var myMap;
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.797068, 110.370529);
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  ,
        scrollwheel: false
    }
    myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

This is my code to call google map, and I tried to add a marker in the map.

Answer (score 1):

Just read Google maps  [**documentation**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=ru)

For adding marker you need to call **Marker** object from google maps API and give relevant properties

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatLng, // For position your marker
     map: map, //For your google map element
});
```

And one important thing.

Google maps api source script tag must be **after your js code** not before.